# What is the most standard functionality to save ExtJS data to server?

Tags: forms, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4, save

It seems there are several ways to interact with MVC stores and save data (sending data to the server side stack) using ExtJS functionality.  I'm finding that Sencha supports several standard methodologies (from what I've read so far), but I'm trying to choose the best one for different parts of my application.  I'm using Ext Direct for my server side stack, but I'm not sure if that makes any difference.  I realize that some methods add data to a store as 'dirty', and some methods send data to the server.  Please correct any descriptions below if I've made a mistake.  **If you can at least get me in the right direction (for my 3 use cases) so I don't waste a lot of time fixing custom code when I need to upgrade to ExtJS 5.x, that would be very much appreciated.**

1. `{form}.submit()` - this sends a JSON request to the server, and is generally used in forms with a single level of data (meaning no nested data structures).
2. `{store}.save()` - seems to save data to the server
3. `{store}.sync()` - seems to send dirty records to the server for a given store
4. `{store}.autoSync` - config for automatically calling `{store}.sync()`
5. `{record}.updateRecord()` - sends updated record to the server
6. `{store}.commit({record})` - seems to be updating a record in a store without actually sending anything to the server
7. `{store}.add()` - seems to only be used for adding a dirty record to a store without actually sending anything to the server?
8. `{model}.save()` - seems to save data in a similar way as `{store}.save()` but seems to be used when model associations are used to build referential integrity between MVC models
9. using standard `{proxy}.writer`
10. extending `{proxy}.writer`
11. overriding `{proxy}.write()` event listener ??

***AM I MISSING ANY (apart from various proxies Sencha supports)?***

**Requests:**

**(1)** I want to be able to save records in a form with fields with a depth of one (meaning no nested data structures).  So, the form contains my entity, with attributes and values.

**(2)** I want to be able to save records in a component (form) with nested components (forms).  Each component can have attribute/value pairs as well as grids.

**(3)** I want to be able to save changes to tree component store data.  I understand model associations (for reads).  What is the best way to save data in a tree that's dirty?  Sending the whole tree down to the server seems like a lot of work, because in a read, I'm only retrieving one level at a time to add to my store.

...

This was neat, but I don't want to get too complex until I understand the basics.
http://moduscreate.com/expert-ext-js-model-integration-in-forms/

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257319-What-is-the-best-pattern-practice-for-saving-nested-data-in-ExtJs-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I used to work with different stores with CRUD in each. 
But that complicated data synchronizing operation because it parts sync process on separate operations, so you cannot sync your data with nested items in the same time.

I think proxy's writer the best way to provide the things you're talking about.
With customizing it you can send plain data or some complex structures.
In my practice I'm using such approach. 
Below is example of writer with sub datas.

```
  writer: {
        type: "json",
        getRecordData: function (record, operation) {
            var data = record.getData();
            var s = [];
            record.subdivisions().each(function(subdivision) {
                var d = subdivision.getData();
                d.organizationId = data.id;
                s.push(d);
            });
            data.subdivisions = s;
            return data;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Years later, I'm coming back to this.  I'll add a note here.  I should have written {store}.proxy.writer in my question.  I hadn't worked with proxies--just read about them.

Comment: I have the opportunity to switch client frameworks and might start using Angular since they don't have all the nonsense with licensing that Sencha has.

Answer (score 1):

you can send your request through ext Ajax. Assuming you have success response you can inform the user with the change you have made and if need be you just reload your store upon success. I think it may help someone.